# php bin/console doctrine:database:create this problem appeared (i'm using symfony4)

Tags: php, html, mysql, symfony, symfony-1.4

C:\projet1\locationvoiture>php bin/console doctrine:database:create

In AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 79:

An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver

In PDOConnection.php line 31:

could not find driver

In PDOConnection.php line 27:

could not find driver

doctrine:database:create [-s|--shard SHARD] [-c|--connection [CONNECTION]] [--if-not-exists] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--]

Comment: Can you please share the output of `php -m` command?

Comment: Update the question with the output ;-)

Comment: C:\projet1\locationvoiture>php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
imap
intl
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_sqlite
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]

Comment: @JovanPerovic here it is

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini, uncomment the line ;extension=pdo_pgsql

Comment: can you share your doctrine.yml configuration please ?

Comment: i can not comment those files i don't know why (i'm new to stack overflow)